# Duplicating logic in methods and scopes (and sql)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Named scopes really made this problem easier but it is far from being solved. The common situation is to have logic redefined in both named scopes and model methods.

I'll try to demonstrate the edge case of this by using somewhat complex example. Lets say that we have `Message` model that has many `Recipients`. Each recipient is being able to mark the message as being read for himself.

If you want to get the list of unread messages for given user, you would say something like this:

```
Message.unread_for(user)
```

That would use the named scope `unread_for` that would generate the sql which will return the unread messages for given user. This sql is probably going to join two tables together and filter messages by those recipients that haven't already read them.

On the other hand, when we are using the `Message` model in our code, we are using the following:

```
message.unread_by?(user)
```

This method is defined in message class and even it is doing basically the same thing, it now has different implementation.

For simpler projects, this is really not a big thing. Implementing the same simple logic in both sql and ruby in this case is not a problem.

But when application starts to get really complex, it starts to be a problem. If we have permission system implemented that checks who is able to access what message based on dozens of criteria defined in dozens of tables, this starts to get very complex. Soon it comes to the point where you need to join 5 tables and write really complex sql by hand in order to define the scope.

The only "clean" solution to the problem is to make the scopes use the actual ruby code. They would fetch ALL messages, and then filter them with ruby. However, this causes two major problems:

1. Performance
2. Pagination

Performance: we are creating a lot more queries to the database. I am not sure about internals of DMBS, but how harder is it for database to execute 5 queries each on single table, or 1 query that is going to join 5 tables at once?

Pagination: we want to keep fetching records until specified number of records is being retrieved. We fetch them one by one and check whether it is accepted by ruby logic. Once 10 of them are accepted, process will stop.

Curious to hear your thoughts on this. I have no experience with nosql dbms, can they tackle the issue in different way?

UPDATE:

I was only speaking hypotetical, but here is one real life example. Lets say that we want to display all transactions on the one page (both payments and expenses).

I have created SQL UNION QUERY to get them both, then go through each record, check whether it could be :read by current user and finally paginated it as an array.

```
def form_transaction_log
  sql1 = @project.payments
                 .select("'Payment' AS record_type, id, created_at")
                 .where('expense_id IS NULL')
                 .to_sql
  sql2 = @project.expenses
                 .select("'Expense' AS record_type, id, created_at")
                 .to_sql

  result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute %{
    (#{sql1} UNION #{sql2})
    ORDER BY created_at DESC
  }

  result = result.map do |record|
    klass = Object.const_get record["record_type"]
    klass.find record["id"]
  end.select do |record|
    can? :read, record
  end

  @transactions = Kaminari.paginate_array(result).page(params[:page]).per(7)
end
```

Both `payments` and `expenses` need to be displayed within same table, ordered by creation date and paginated.

Both `payments` and `expenses` have completely different `:read` permissions (defined in ability class, `CanCan` gem). These permission are quite complex and they require querieng several other tables.

The "ideal" thing would be to write one HUGE sql query that would do return what I need. It would made pagination and everything else a lot easier. But that is going to duplicate my logic defined in ability.rb class.

I'm aware that `CanCan` provides a way of defining the sql query for the ability, but the abilities are so complex, that they couldn't be defined in that way.

What I did is working, but I'm loading ALL transactions, and then checking which ones I could read. I consider it a big performance issue. Pagination here seems pointless because I'm already loading all records (it only saves bandwidth). An alternative is to write really complex SQL that is going to be hard to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should remove some duplication and perhaps use DB logic more. There's no reason that you can't share code between named scopes between other methods.

Can you post some problematic code for review?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've included one real-life example above.